# Raspberry pi 3 problem with 'make install_autostart' command when installing servoblaster

Tags: pi-3, software-installation

I am working to create a pan/tilt face tracking system on the raspberry pi 3 and have been following the instructions on http://www.instructables.com/id/Pan-Tilt-face-tracking-with-the-raspberry-pi/

I have followed the instructions but when I go to do the

```
make install_autostart
```

command for `servoblaster` I get the error

```
*** No rule to make target 'install_autostart'.  Stop.
```

I am very new to all of this and have spent many hours trying to figure this out and would appreciate any feedback. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be an ancient instructable for the Pi, perhaps from 2013, which is an age in Pi terms.

The `make install_autostart` command seems to be associated with the kernel module version of servoblaster which I doubt anyone actually uses any more.

You should probably be installing the user daemon version of servoblaster.

Both versions are available at https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster

For instructions search half way down the README.txt for `The user space daemon`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Joan I greatly appreciate your time.

Comment: Would you know where I could find the daemon version of servoblaster by chance?